# Get data from the server in the main thread in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http, request

How can I get data from the server in the main thread?

**For example, in the class anybodyclass.swift I'll write**

```
// initialization
print(HttpClassForGetData().result)
print("This will only work when the class is initialized and any data will be loaded")
```

The class in which I try to get data from the server and write them to the object variable: HttpClassForGetData.swift

```
// Data class
import UIKit

class HttpClassForGetData: NSObject {

    var result: Any? = nil

    init() {

        // create post request
        let url = URL("example.com")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate:nil, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)
        var DATA = session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request)
        result = DATA

        // continue work in anybodyclass.swift class

    }

}
```

After that, the print() method does not have to work until the class HttpClassForGetData is initialized.
thank!

// detail

So you understand me, what I need. Describe the implementation of the example of Java.

```
// UI Thread Android
new Thread(new Runnable(
    @Overide
    String var = null;
    void run() {
        int command = 1;
        HttpClass data = new HttpClass(command);
        if (data.result != null) Activity.runUiThread(new Runnable(
            @Overide
            void run() {
                // View in class
                view.setText("OK. Data is load " + data.result)
            }
        )).start();
        else var = "not OK";
        Log.d("test", var + "");
    }
)).start();
....
```

Comment: The thread is irrelevant to your issue. The problem is that this is an asynchronous process. You should not make any attempt to get it work with a simple call such as `HttpClassForGetData().result`.

Comment: That is, I can not get the program to hang while the request is executed?

Comment: You could write your code to "hang" while the data is loaded from the server but you shouldn't and if you call it from the main queue, you must not. Embrace the fact that it should be done asynchronously and write your code accordingly.

Comment: rmaddy is right. If want you wait is the UI to wait patiently while the request is processed the answer is not to hang the main thread. Show a loading indicator and/or disable buttons and user interactions. After the request is processed on a background thread return to the main thread and enable user interactions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use semaphore as an option to achieve this.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0) // create semaphore

// Do your stuff
[self methodWithABlock:^(id result){
    //put code here
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);

    [self methodWithABlock:^(id result){
        //put code here
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem); // once get response give signal to semaphore
    }]
}]

// wait the thread forever
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

**Swift code below**

```
// Data class
import UIKit

class HttpClassForGetData: NSObject {

    var result: Any? = nil
    var sem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0) // create semaphore

    init() {

        // create post request
        let url = URL("example.com")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate:nil, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)
        var DATA = session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request) // use uploadTask with completion handler API here.
        result = DATA

        // continue work in anybodyclass.swift class
        _ = sem.wait(timeout: .distantFuture) // lock calling thread, put this code at the end
    }

}
```

Now configure your `URLSession` not in the main queue. And use `session.uploadTask` completion handler API, and in your API call completion block call `self.sem.signal()` method.

Comment: i need implementation on Swift 4 this